# how would I get the selected checkboxes from the combobox? Give example to get the selected check box values from combo box

Tags: gwt-ext

I am looking for something like combobox with checkbox selection(second one on that page, the picklist):

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#multi_select_combobox_category

please give code snippet to get selected checkboxes values from combobox in GWT EXT.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LovCombo, this component implements a combobox with checkboxes inside. Take a look at: http://lovcombo.extjs.eu/

Comment: And the example the TS links does as well, but his problem is he can't get the selected items.